# Transparent Controls and a Flicker-Free MFC Dialog

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mfc, flicker

Is it possible to have in a dialog-based MFC app both:

1. Transparent static controls
2. A flicker-free continuously changing background *(edit: background might be complex with different colors/shapes at the same time)*

So far I have only managed to achieve one at a time. For the static control transparency, I simply add a Static text control and override the dialog's `OnCtlColor` handler function to set the background mode to `TRANSPARENT` for static controls like the following:

```cpp
// In the header
afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);

// In the source file
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyMFCDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR() // Add this handle
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

HBRUSH CMyMFCDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    if (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_STATIC)
    {
        SetBkMode(*pDC, TRANSPARENT);
        return (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    }

    return hbr;
}
```

It works like a charm, we can see it even more cleary by changing the Dialog's background color in the `OnPaint` handler function:

```cpp
int r = 255, g = 0, b = 0;

void CMyMFCDialog::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        // ... Unchanged code
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();

        CDC* dc = this->GetDC();
        CRect cr;
        GetClientRect(&cr);
        dc->FillSolidRect(cr, RGB(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

[image: Basic MFC Dialog with a transparent text and a red background]

And for the continuously changing background, I simply change the RGB values of the precedently filled background very rapidly. In order to do that I will simply add a button control, set its ID to `IDC_BUTTON1` and handle its `OnBnClicked` event to change the RGB values around every 1ms like so:

```cpp
// In the header 
afx_msg void OnBnClickedButton1();

// In the source file
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyMFCDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMyMFCDialog::OnBnClickedButton1) // Add this handle
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyMFCDialog::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (r > 0 && b == 0) {
            r--; g++;
        }
        if (g > 0 && r == 0) {
            g--; b++;
        }
        if (b > 0 && g == 0) {
            r++; b--;
        }

        Invalidate();
        UpdateWindow();
        Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

[image: Basic MFC Dialog with a transparent text and a background changing colors and flickering]

And as one could expect, it does flicker like crazy. I tried multiple things (more details below) and what worked the best was to edit the .rc file to add `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to the dialog's style flags:

```cpp
IDD_MYMFCDIALOG_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 320, 200
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,209,179,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,263,179,50,14
    CTEXT           "TODO: Place dialog controls here.",IDC_STATIC,10,96,300,8
    PUSHBUTTON      "Button1",IDC_BUTTON1,239,46,50,14
END
```

And override the `OnEraseBkgnd` handler function to return `TRUE` or `FALSE`:

```cpp
// In the header 
afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);

// In the source file
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyMFCDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND() // Add this handle
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMyMFCDialog::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

[image: Basic MFC Dialog with a not-transparent text and a color changing background with no flickering]

It successfully removed the flickering effect, but now our freshly made-transparent static text control has its white background back. I tried making a custom CStatic class to override its `OnPaint` and `OnCtlColor` in order to set its Background Mode to `TRANSPARENT` but to no avail, the white background is still there.

I also tried disabling `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to implement double buffering using multiple methods, first, manually:

```cpp
void CMyMFCDialog::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        // ... Unchanged code
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();

        CDC* dc = this->GetDC();
        CDC memDC;
        CBitmap bmpDC, *pOldBmp;

        memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
        CRect cr;
        GetClientRect(&cr);
        bmpDC.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, cr.Width(), cr.Height());
        pOldBmp = memDC.SelectObject(&bmpDC);

        memDC.FillSolidRect(cr, RGB(r, g, b));

        dc->BitBlt(cr.left, cr.top, cr.Width(), cr.Height(), &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        memDC.SelectObject(pOldBmp);
    }
}
```

It unfortunately still flickers, I've tried copying that double buffering code into custom `CStatic` classes `OnPaint` handle functions to see if it would work better but nothing changed pretty much.

I tried then to use some already implemented double buffering, first by using the [CMemeDC header made by Keith Rule in 2002](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC), and renaming both the file and class to `MyCMemDC` since there seems to be a conflict with an already existing CMemDC class:

```cpp
// In pch.h
#include "mycmemdc.h"

// In the main source file
void CMyMFCDialog::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        // ... Unchanged code
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();

        CDC* dc = this->GetDC();
        MyCMemDC memDC(&dc);

        memDC.FillSolidRect(cr, RGB(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

Flicker is still happening, so I tried to dig in the official `CMemDC` class, and it seems to also be a double buffering implementation, so I tried to use it as well:

```cpp
void CMyMFCDialog::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        // ... Unchanged code
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();

        CDC* dc = this->GetDC();
        CRect cr;
        GetClientRect(&cr);
        CMemDC memDC(*dc, &cr);
        CDC* pDC = &memDC.GetDC();

        pDC->FillSolidRect(cr, RGB(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

And the result was still flickery sadly.

I might have missed something or poorly implemented double buffering, the code above should allow for an easy reproduction of my problem, I tried to explain almost every step, even though some can be skipped by using the Class Wizard. Feel free to ask for any details I may have forgot to include.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to have a message handler to `WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC` and return a brush of the exact same color as the background drawn by your paint function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-ctlcolorstatic

Comment: Yes this could work if the background behind the static control is only made of one color like the basic example I provided. However it would not look that good if the background is more complex and contains different shapes or colors behind the control, which is why I'm looking for some transparency that could be possible no matter the background.

Comment: @Saliom - Then instead of using a static text control, do you own [DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) inside WM_PAINT after the background is drawn.

Comment: After some testing DrawText is a viable solution for text, I had to couple it with manual double buffering to avoid some flickering on it but it does work. I imagine drawing every control manually could do the job but I'm afraid it might start to become messy and handling the events even messier over time compared to handling serparate static control's events.

Comment: In other words, you want to accomplish something that is easily done with a modern desktop framework (e.g. XAML, Qt, Flutter, React, etc....).  But you're trying to do it using MFC - on a dialog, no less.  MFC hasn't been actively worked on by Microsoft in over a decade, maybe longer.  All the modern UX framework essentially double-buffer for you so you can just use your controls without having to think about it.

Comment: Yes my initial choice to build an app in MFC was purely based on the thought that it would be the best suited for communication with a self-made driver with low-level windows functions like [DeviceIoControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-deviceiocontrol), but the more I attempt to do GUI stuff the more I see the limitations of this (old) framework.